# custom commands for centos

Tags: linux, centos

How to create a custom command application for centos.when user login it should load and allow user to execute custom commands. Didn't find any open source app for this.

custom command :change ip
new ip:0.0.0.0
ip changed successfully

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site. Please bear in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service, and your question will need to be specific, as well as show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if i understand, but i believe that if you are looking for a command that start within a user ssh connection, you can define a task in the user's .bash_profile

At the end of that, you can add a call to your own script|command and it should start immediately after the ssh login.